# Accessing an array inside an Object

Tags: extjs4

I have an array inside an object an I'm trying to access the contents of the array but I cant seem to get the syntax correct. I'm using chrome and the debugger that comes with it. the Code below shows the object and the array and my attempts to access it. What is wrong with what I'm doing?

The code in my application:

```
var responseText = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
alert(responseText.errors[0]);
```

The using the chrome console:

```
responseText.errors
  Object
    : Array[1]
      0: "Error Message"
      length: 1
      __proto__: Array[0]
  __proto__: Object

responseText.errors[0]
undefined

responseText.errors.Array
undefined

responseText.errors.Array[0]
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

In my mind it should be a simple matter of using the third attempt. It's baffling me as to why its undefined!

Comment: doesn't your array have a name assigned in the object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises with the Array not having named Objects.

The server code created an array of messages, but there were no keys passed with the messages to either determine what they were for, or get access to them. I have since added some keys to the array objects and the js code now works.

@VoidMain, no that wont work either. there is no way to access the elements without, as you said, a name being set on the sever.

(I figured this out and had this answer 7.5 hours ago, but couldn't post it. Very annoying)

Answer (score 0):

Its a 0 as the name of the property, bad idea... Anyway, you can access it like this:

```
responseText.errors['0']
```

But, try to change it in your server, get some more friendly names...